# Align value counts of two dataframes side by side

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

If I have two dataframes - df1 (data for current day), and df2 (data for previous day).

Both dataframes have 40 columns, and all columns are object data type.

how do I compare Top 3 value_counts for both dataframes, ideally so that the result is side by side, like the following;

```
                  df1                  df2

Column a          Value count 1       Value count 1
                  Value count 2       Value count 2
                  Value count 3       Value count 3   


Column b         Value count 1        Value count 1
                 Value count 2        Value count 2 
                 Value count 3        Value count 3
```

The main idea is to check for data anomalies between the data for the two days.

I only know that for each column per dataframe, I must do something like this -

```
df1.Column.value_counts().head(3)
```

But this doesn't show combined results as I want. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare if same columns names in both DataFrames - first use lambda function with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), top3 and create default index for both DataFrames and then join them with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and for expected order add [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
np.random.seed(2022)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(50,5))).add_prefix('c')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(50,5))).add_prefix('c')

df11 = df1.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(3).reset_index(drop=True))
df22 = df2.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(3).reset_index(drop=True))


df = pd.concat([df11, df22], axis=1, keys=('df1','df2')).stack().sort_index(level=1)
print (df)
      df1  df2
0 c0    7    8
1 c0    6    8
2 c0    6    6
0 c1    8    9
1 c1    7    7
2 c1    7    7
0 c2    9    7
1 c2    7    7
2 c2    7    6
0 c3    9    7
1 c3    7    7
2 c3    7    6
0 c4   11   14
1 c4    7    8
2 c4    7    7
```

Or use [`DataFrame.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html):

```
df = (df11.compare(df22,keep_equal=True)
          .rename(columns={'self':'df1','other':'df2'})
          .stack(0)
          .sort_index(level=1))
print (df)

      df1  df2
0 c0    7    8
1 c0    6    8
2 c0    6    6
0 c1    8    9
1 c1    7    7
2 c1    7    7
0 c2    9    7
1 c2    7    7
2 c2    7    6
0 c3    9    7
1 c3    7    7
2 c3    7    6
0 c4   11   14
1 c4    7    8
2 c4    7    7
```

EDIT: For add categories use `f-strings` for join indices and values of Series in list comprehension:

```
np.random.seed(2022)
df1 = 'Cat1' + pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(50,5))).add_prefix('c').astype(str)
df2 = 'Cat2' + pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(50,5))).add_prefix('c').astype(str)

df11 = df1.apply(lambda x: [f'{a} - {b}' for a, b in x.value_counts().head(3).items()])
df22 = df2.apply(lambda x:[f'{a} - {b}' for a, b in x.value_counts().head(3).items()])

df = pd.concat([df11, df22], axis=1, keys=('df1','df2')).stack().sort_index(level=1)
print (df)
             df1         df2
0 c0   Cat18 - 7   Cat29 - 8
1 c0   Cat11 - 6   Cat24 - 8
2 c0   Cat19 - 6   Cat23 - 6
0 c1   Cat17 - 8   Cat24 - 9
1 c1   Cat10 - 7   Cat26 - 7
2 c1   Cat14 - 7   Cat20 - 7
0 c2   Cat13 - 9   Cat28 - 7
1 c2   Cat11 - 7   Cat25 - 7
2 c2   Cat19 - 7   Cat26 - 6
0 c3   Cat15 - 9   Cat20 - 7
1 c3   Cat18 - 7   Cat24 - 7
2 c3   Cat13 - 7   Cat27 - 6
0 c4  Cat12 - 11  Cat25 - 14
1 c4   Cat13 - 7   Cat20 - 8
2 c4   Cat15 - 7   Cat26 - 7
```

Comment: But I am just getting the value counts, is there any way to add the value label it relates to as well? I'm sorry if this was not apparent in the question. For example, "Category A - 87"

Comment: @Ray92 - give me a sec.

Comment: @Ray92 - added to answer.

Comment: I hope you always live a happy life, thanks so much  jezrael    :)

Comment: I am running into a problem here, can you please help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72912897/aligning-two-lengthy-data-frames-side-by-side

Comment: Maybe it is because for some columns, there is only one or two value_counts (not 3)?