# Aligning two lengthy data frames side by side

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

So basically I am following this solution:
[Align value counts of two dataframes side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72907091/align-value-counts-of-two-dataframes-side-by-side)

I am implementing the code, but instead of getting the result as shown in the answer posted
by jezrael, I am getting this format (please note df_curr_obj, and df_old_obj are my 2 dataframes):

```
_id                          df_curr_obj    [472d5fe8-7 - 1, 0e1eb4d8-5 - 1, 2996b2de-5 - 1]   
_id_reason                   df_curr_obj    [1348fbc6-7 - 1, 0ee0661f-d - 1, a8c03816-c - 1]   
_rev                         df_curr_obj    [v1 - 93, v2 - 1]                                  
_rev_reason                  df_curr_obj    [v1 - 92, v2 - 1]                                  
baseentityid                 df_curr_obj    [f32e9041-3 - 2, 4411bc0f-9 - 1, 1c7b44b1-d - 1]   
baseentityid_reason          df_curr_obj    [4411bc0f-9 - 1, 9568a3b1-b - 1, aa6eacf4-c - 1]   
current_pregnancy_id_reason  df_curr_obj    [790e4b21-2 - 1, 75d82e1a-c - 1, 1c89ec5d-5 - 1]   
device_identifier            df_curr_obj    [648f1a44-6 - 31, 667a945a-f - 24, 30a009f9-c - 12]
device_identifier_reason     df_curr_obj    [648f1a44-6 - 31, 667a945a-f - 24, 30a009f9-c - 12]
edd                          df_curr_obj    [02/08/2022 - 3, 01/11/2022 - 3, 23/10/2022 - 2]   
entitytype                   df_curr_obj    [1348fbc6-7 - 1, 0ee0661f-d - 1, 76b45696-0 - 1]   
facility_reason              df_curr_obj    [Qayumabad - 31, Ali Akbar  - 24, Bhains Col - 12] 
fetalheartbeat               df_curr_obj    [PRESENT - 92]                                     
formsubmissionid             df_curr_obj    [472d5fe8-7 - 1, 0e1eb4d8-5 - 1, 2996b2de-5 - 1]   
formsubmissionid_reason      df_curr_obj    [1348fbc6-7 - 1, 0ee0661f-d - 1, a8c03816-c - 1]   
lie                          df_curr_obj    [LONGITUDIN - 29, OBLIQUE - 2, TRANSVERSE - 1]     
liquordescription            df_curr_obj    [ADEQUATE - 78, SCANTY - 2, EXCESS - 1]            
locationid                   df_curr_obj    [AG - 24, BH - 12, IH - 7]                         
locationid_reason            df_curr_obj    [AG - 24, BH - 12, IH - 7]                         
otherfetalanomalies          df_curr_obj    [pleural ef - 1, unilateral - 1]                   
placenta_previa              df_curr_obj    [NO - 62, DONT_KNOW - 1, YES - 1]                  
placental_abruption          df_curr_obj    [NO - 63, DONT_KNOW - 2]                           
placentallocalization        df_curr_obj    [notLowLyin - 44, anteriorWa - 15, posteriorW - 10]
presence_of_fetal_anomalies  df_curr_obj    [others - 2]                                       
presentation                 df_curr_obj    [CEPHALIC - 30, BREECH - 2]                        
providerid                   df_curr_obj    [qasonologi - 31, agsonologi - 24, bhsonologi - 12]
providerid_reason            df_curr_obj    [qasonologi - 31, agsonologi - 24, bhsonologi - 12]
serverversion                df_curr_obj    [2022-07-07 - 94]                                  
serverversion_reason         df_curr_obj    [2022-07-07 - 93]                                  
task_id                      df_curr_obj    [2ad74e31-2 - 1, dcb1a9c5-e - 1, e835b894-f - 1]   
task_id_reason               df_curr_obj    [2ad74e31-2 - 1, 2b450eb6-1 - 1, 4dda40a1-e - 1]   
taskid_reason                df_curr_obj    [2ad74e31-2 - 1, 2b450eb6-1 - 1, 4dda40a1-e - 1]   
team                         df_curr_obj    [VITAL-QB - 31, VITAL-AG-A - 24, VITAL-BH-A - 12]  
team_reason                  df_curr_obj    [VITAL-QB - 31, VITAL-AG-A - 24, VITAL-BH-A - 12]  
teamid                       df_curr_obj    [VITAL-QB - 31, VITAL-AG-A - 24, VITAL-BH-A - 12]  
teamid_reason                df_curr_obj    [VITAL-QB - 31, VITAL-AG-A - 24, VITAL-BH-A - 12]  
ultrasound_reasons_reason    df_curr_obj    [[Gestation - 93]                                  
ultrasoundreasons_reason     df_curr_obj    [[Gestation - 93]                                  
version                      df_curr_obj    [2022-07-07 - 94]                                  
version_reason               df_curr_obj    [2022-07-07 - 93]                                  
_id                          df_old_obj     [4015790d-3 - 1, b106e1f3-5 - 1, 25880919-6 - 1]   
_id_reason                   df_old_obj     [46135f86-9 - 1, 4faeeeb6-0 - 1, c0995147-f - 1]   
_rev                         df_old_obj     [v1 - 47]                                          
_rev_reason                  df_old_obj     [v1 - 47]                                          
baseentityid                 df_old_obj     [c747f7bc-9 - 1, 5665e9c7-1 - 1, ee2b5683-a - 1]   
baseentityid_reason          df_old_obj     [c747f7bc-9 - 1, 5665e9c7-1 - 1, ee2b5683-a - 1]   
current_pregnancy_id_reason  df_old_obj     [5c8942f4-5 - 1, 2095aa4f-4 - 1, feab7c3f-7 - 1]   
device_identifier            df_old_obj     [648f1a44-6 - 15, cb7fb229-9 - 10, 6e627f53-e - 8] 
device_identifier_reason     df_old_obj     [648f1a44-6 - 15, cb7fb229-9 - 10, 6e627f53-e - 8] 
edd                          df_old_obj     [24/08/2022 - 2, 10/08/2022 - 2, 31/01/2023 - 2]   
entitytype                   df_old_obj     [46135f86-9 - 1, 4faeeeb6-0 - 1, c0995147-f - 1]   
facility_reason              df_old_obj     [Qayumabad - 15, Sukhiya Go - 10, Ibrahim Hy - 8]  
fetalheartbeat               df_old_obj     [PRESENT - 47]                                     
formsubmissionid             df_old_obj     [4015790d-3 - 1, b106e1f3-5 - 1, 25880919-6 - 1]   
formsubmissionid_reason      df_old_obj     [46135f86-9 - 1, 4faeeeb6-0 - 1, c0995147-f - 1]   
lie                          df_old_obj     [LONGITUDIN - 10, TRANSVERSE - 1]                  
liquordescription            df_old_obj     [ADEQUATE - 37, SCANTY - 1]                        
locationid                   df_old_obj     [IH - 8, BH - 5, AG - 5]                           
locationid_reason            df_old_obj     [IH - 8, BH - 5, AG - 5]                           
placenta_previa              df_old_obj     [NO - 22, YES - 1]                                 
placental_abruption          df_old_obj     [NO - 22]                                          
placentallocalization        df_old_obj     [notLowLyin - 15, posteriorW - 7, anteriorWa - 5]  
presentation                 df_old_obj     [CEPHALIC - 10]                                    
providerid                   df_old_obj     [qasonologi - 15, sgsonologi - 10, ihsonologi - 8] 
providerid_reason            df_old_obj     [qasonologi - 15, sgsonologi - 10, ihsonologi - 8] 
serverversion                df_old_obj     [2022-07-06 - 47]                                  
serverversion_reason         df_old_obj     [2022-07-06 - 47]                                  
task_id                      df_old_obj     [8edc3bd4-f - 1, 5b2c076a-3 - 1, 4eb35473-e - 1]   
task_id_reason               df_old_obj     [8edc3bd4-f - 1, 5b2c076a-3 - 1, 4eb35473-e - 1]   
taskid_reason                df_old_obj     [8edc3bd4-f - 1, 5b2c076a-3 - 1, 4eb35473-e - 1]   
team                         df_old_obj     [VITAL-QB - 15, VITAL-SG - 10, VITAL-IH-A - 8]     
team_reason                  df_old_obj     [VITAL-QB - 15, VITAL-SG - 10, VITAL-IH-A - 8]     
teamid                       df_old_obj     [VITAL-QB - 15, VITAL-SG - 10, VITAL-IH-A - 8]     
teamid_reason                df_old_obj     [VITAL-QB - 15, VITAL-SG - 10, VITAL-IH-A - 8]     
ultrasound_reasons_reason    df_old_obj     [[Gestation - 47]                                  
ultrasoundreasons_reason     df_old_obj     [[Gestation - 47]                                  
version                      df_old_obj     [2022-07-06 - 47]                                  
version_reason               df_old_obj     [2022-07-06 - 47]                                  
dtype: object
```

I have tried increasing the the number of rows / columns displayed and increasing column width,
but this has no affect.

Maybe it is because for some columns, there is only one or two value_counts (not 3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried a few things myself, and the following code update gets the result
close to the desired format:

```
df_final = pd.concat([df11, df22], axis=1, keys=('df_curr_obj','df_old_obj')).stack().sort_index()
```